# How can I make a banner in QT, like the news banner of CNN/FOX?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, banner

as the title says, I want to add my main window a banner in the bottom of the window that shows text that runs from left to right, just like you can see in your TV when watching fox/CNN...

I'm using QT 4.5.2

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Embed an HTML rendering control and use the <marquee> tag. :)

Comment: If you can change to Qt 4.6, they include an animation framework that might help you with this.

Answer (score 3):

You have many options.  You could:

- Create a custom widget and override [`QWidget::paintEvent()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html#paintEvent)
- Drawing your text to an [image](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qpixmap.html) and then repainting that image as often as needed
- Creating a [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsscene.html) and then moving an appropriate [text item](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicstextitem.html) around.

[QTimeline](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtimeline.html) and/or [QTimer](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtimer.html) will likely be useful in your implementation.  The key idea is that you need to draw something at different positions at consistent intervals.  If you redraw frequently enough, it will look like an animation.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try to implement it.